# How to get Resource details using GetByUser(user) REST API in Share Point?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I want to get the resource details of a logged user. I am using the REST API http:////_api/ProjectServer/EnterpriseResources/getByUser(user). Which parameter may I pass in the getByUser method?

Is there any REST API for getting resource details?

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of logged on user using REST in sharepoint 2013 i use this REST endpoint

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser"
```